# Integrating login function inside a Class

Tags: python, class, object, orientation

sorry for my nooby question; I had a python application with only functions but now I have to revise it with classes that I am not expert on.

Here is my basic user Class;

```
class User:

def __init__(self,username,password,basket):
    self.username=username
    self.password=password
    self.basket=basket
```

and the input function that I want to put inside the class;

```
    def Login(self):
    while True:
        username = raw_input('\nPlease log in by providing your user credentials \nUser Name :')

        if (username == users[0]['username'] or username == users[1]['username']):
            password = raw_input('Password : ')
            if (password == users[0]['password'] or password == users[1]['password']):
                print('Successfully logged in!')
                print (
                'Welcome,' + username + '! Please choose of the following options by entering the corresponding menu number.')
                global LoggedUserName
                LoggedUserName = username;
                return True;
                break;
            else:
                print('Your password is not correct. Please try again!')
        else:
            print ('Your username is not correct. Please try again!')
```

Thank you for your precious helps!

Comment: What is the problem here? What error are you getting?

Comment: @match I should put the function inside the class

Comment: The function takes self, and is indented to be in the class (albeit the contents aren't indented properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make instance of your class like that
Aname=User()
Aname.login()
But im not sure im too newbie object orriented programming